# how to replace output on first line with different output

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, terminal

i am trying to create a line of code that prints the first line like it normally would do then after printing it, it will then erase that output and write something else

```
print("This text is about to vanish - from first line",end='')
import time
time.sleep(3)
print("\rSame line output by Thirumalai")
```

i have this code from another user, how would i go about having it so that it shows the first line aswell, because when i run the py in terminal it doesnt do that, im using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

To make the first line appear, you need to turn off buffering. You can specify

```
print("This text is about to vanish - from first line",end='', flush=True)
#                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~
```

for the `print` (Python 3.3+ needed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/1030675) for the details and ways how to do that in older versions).

You also need to print some spaces at the end of the second `print` to overwrite the remaining text.

```
print("\rSame line output by Thirumalai", ' ' * 15)
```

Comment: "thanks" on StackOverflow = Upvote / Accept

Comment: is there anyway to have ```flush=True``` always enabled so that if affects all lines of the code until it specifically told to stop, instead of typing it out all the time

Comment: See the linked question and answers for more details.